# Rails 3 - Am I making config files too complicated?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, app-config

I'm a simple guy— I just want a YAML config file that's accessible from controllers. That's all.

First, I created `config/app_config.yml`, which contains the config values I want. So far, so good.

Then, in I created `lib/app_config.rb`, which contains:

```
module AppConfig
  def self.config
    @@config ||= {}
  end

  def self.config=(config)
    @@config = config
  end
end
```

Finally, I created `config/initializers/load_app_config.rb`, which contains:

```
# the ./ is necessary for some reason, though no examples online use it...
require './lib/app_config'

AppConfig.config = YAML.load_file("#{Rails.root.to_s}/config/app_config.yml")
```

Should I skip `load_app_config.rb` altogether, and assign `AppConfig.config` some other way (perhaps inside of the module itself)?

It seems I'm making it too complicated..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making it a little more complicated than it needs to be. You only need 2 things:

Your conifg: /config/config.yml
(should look something like this, of course these are just placeholders)

```
development: &DEVELOPMENT
  host_name: "localhost:3000"
  api_username: test@example.com
  api_pass: password
  api_key: 12345
test:
  <<: *DEVELOPMENT
cucumber:
  <<: *DEVELOPMENT
staging:
  host_name: "my-staging-staging.heroku.com"
  api_username: test@example.com
  api_pass: password
  api_key: 12345
  s3:
    bucket: bucket-name
    access_key_id: secret_key_id
    secret_access_key: secret_key
production:
  host_name: "my-production.heroku.com"
  api_username: test@example.com
  api_pass: password
  api_key: 12345
  s3:
    bucket: bucket-name
    access_key_id: secret_key_id
    secret_access_key: secret_key
```

Then your initializer: /config/initializers/app_config.rb

```
AppConfig = YAML.load(File.read(Rails.root + 'config' + 'config.yml'))[Rails.env].with_indifferent_access
```

Now you can access anything from you config from anywhere via AppConfig. For example to grab the host name in whatever environment you are in would be:

```
AppConfig[:host_name]
```

If we were running locally, that value would be "localhost:3000"

Comment: that was my first approach. However, when I try this, accessing `AppConfig` from my controllers results in an uninitialized-constant error. I just tried it again, and received the same error. Is `AppConfig` defined somewhere special?

Comment: AppConfig is defined in app_config.rb. When your initializer runs, it makes it should make it available. To help troubleshoot whether your initializer is loading correctly, try setting YAML.load(File.read(Rails.root + 'config' + 'config.yml'))[Rails.env].with_indifferent_access somewhere in the controller where you are trying to use it and assign it to 'config' or something. Then try accessing config[:attribute]

Comment: Also can you verify that you have app_config.rb in /config/initializers instead of the one you have in /lib

Answer (score 0):

I use [configatron](https://github.com/markbates/configatron) by Mark Bates, it's the same as AppConfig approach, but it allows to use ERB in YAML and can help to use namespaces:

```
configatron.website_url = "http://www.mackframework.com"
configatron.email.pop.address = "pop.example.com"
configatron.email.pop.port = 110
configatron.email.smtp.address = "smtp.example.com"
configatron.email.smtp.port = 25
```